# How to create an efficient index on many-to-many relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, many-to-many, query-optimization

Here is my use case:
I have two tables: `job` and `employee` that are connected using many-to-many relationship like this (I skipped fields that are unrelated to question):

```
CREATE TABLE jobs (
    id INT,
    status ENUM('todo', 'in-progress', 'done')
);

CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INT
);

CREATE TABLE pivot (
  id INT
  job_id INT
  employee_id INT
);
```

Now I need to extract the current work in progress jobs:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM jobs j
JOIN pivot p ON p.job_id = j.id
WHERE p.employee_id = 123
AND j.status = "in-progress"
```

The issue is scale.
Since I have to keep historic data, I will have more than `10 million` rows in `jobs` that are `done` (even more in `pivot`).
So while this select will usually return one or two rows, both index on `jobs.status` and index on `pivot.employee_id` will return huge number of rows.

Is there any way to create an index that will include both `jobs.status` and `pivot.employee_id` to improve performance of above query?

Answer (score 2):

You can't make any index span multiple tables in MySQL.

Here are the indexes I'd create:

```
ALTER TABLE pivot 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (job_id, employee_id),
  ADD KEY (employee_id, job_id),
  DROP COLUMN id;

ALTER TABLE jobs
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
  ADD KEY (status);

ALTER TABLE employees
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

The `pivot.id` column is probably unnecessary, because the other two columns together are an appropriate primary key.

Comment: I word it more strongly -- `pivot.id` is an unnecessary waste of both space and speed.

Comment: @RickJames Given what the OP has shown so far, I would agree with that. But frequently the example has been simplified for the sake of the post.